# Has Apple any policy for dead/stuck pixel in MacBook Pro Retina

Tags: macbook-pro

I recently purchased a MacBook Pro with Retina display. I always struggled with different kind of problems when I was an owner of other laptops like ASUS, HP, DELL, etc. I wanted   something more reliable.

The new MacBook Pro made me very happy until I noticed a stuck green pixel in the middle of the screen. It showed up 2 weeks after I received my MacBook. My problems start like before with other laptops...

Anyway, I have an appointment at the nearest genius bar but my guess is that they will do nothing for one dead pixel.

So my question is : Is there any Apple worldwide policy for dead/stuck pixels ? What I should be aware of before my appointment to help me with the eventual MacBook replacement ?

I tried to fix it with a different methods that you can find on Internet with no results.

P.S. MacBook was purchased online and the appointment is in one of Paris genius bar.

Comment: If you had noticed the dead pixel within the 14 day return period you'd have had the choice to simply return the machine for a refund or swap it for another new machine. My guess is AppleCare will take care of it with no hassle but in the future, keep that 14 day return period in mind when checking for dead pixels.

Comment: Unfortunately it's a little bit more than 14 days :( I hope genius bar will find a solution for my issue.

Comment: Thomas: I feel your pain. If (when) I had a retina MBP I'd definitely attempt to make this right for fear it would irritate me the entire time I owned the machine. I'm guessing you'll be treated right. Please let us know the outcome when you tell Apple about it. Which store are you planning to go to to take care of this?

Comment: Richard, I'm going to the Paris Opéra genius bar. It will be my first experience with french Apple support as I've always been Windows user. The first contact with macbook was awesome when I switched to osx. I hope the same from the support. I let you know the outcome as soon as I come back from my appoitment.

Comment: READ THIS:

http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/95368/may-i-demand-product-replacement-macbook-pro-retina-will-have-screen-replacemen/

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it would be covered under AppleCare.  They may opt to either fix it or replace it.  But I'm not 100% certain.

Answer (score 1):

I've replaced an iPhone, and a MacBook with dead pixels, they they swapped both on the spot.

It doesn't matter where you buy them from, as long as they are under warranty they will fix/replace them for you.

I would recommend that you either clone your drive with carbon copy cloner, or at least ensure you have an up to date time machine backup in case they are unable to swap the SSD over for you if they do offer to replace it on your visit.

Comment: I've heard that there is a limit of 4 or 5 dead pixels before replacement ?

Comment: It really depends on the mood of the genius on the day. If you're nice to them they are generally a lot more helpful. One of mine had a dead pixel, and the other had a stuck pixel. Both were over 6 months old, and both were replaced on the spot. I also had a suspected faulty wifi module on an iMac, and even though they couldn't replicate the fault in-store they replaced it (they said would take a week to repair, and they did it by 10am the next day). They are generally very good in my experience.

Comment: I'm new to mac osx. I've been Windows user since the very beginning. How to do a carbon copy clone on osx ?

Comment: It's pretty simple to use, all of the documentation can be found here http://www.bombich.com/ccc_support.html

Answer (score 1):

Mine had a single dead pixel after the 14 day period.  They replaced the screen no questions asked.  Had it leave it over night due them not having the parts.