# may I demand product replacement? Macbook Pro Retina will have screen replacement for the 3rd time

Tags: macbook-pro, display, warranty, applecare, price

[image]may I demand product replacement - completely new Macbook Pro Retina?

My 15" Macbook Pro Retina will have screen replacement for the 3rd time.
For the first time it was ghost effect - replaced with new screen,
for the second time bad pixel - replaced with new screen,
and now there is once more bad pixel - maybe it is the time for WHOLE COMPUTER replacment?

Do you know some of the Apple's polices in this area?

May I even demand the warranty coverage prolongation? One such replacement is about one week without computer...

Additionaly to bad pixels something like presented on the picture started happening...

UPDATE regarding ghost effect issue:

http://youtu.be/KdhIA8-UIRQ
The video shows that only the LG-Panels are affected. Unfortunately it seems that the chance of getting a Samsung panel is only about 1/3.

You want to know what kind of Panel/Display your Retina Macbook has?
Simply start your Mac OS X Terminal and type in the following command:

```
ioreg -lw0 | grep \"EDID\" | sed "/[^<]*</s///" | xxd -p -r | strings -6
```

Model numbers beginning with "LP" indicate an LG display.
A number beginning with "LSN" corresponds to a Samsung display

---

## **VERY IMPORTANT UPDATE (2015-02-19):**

### MacBook Pro Repair Extension Program for Video Issues

MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2012)
MacBook Pro (Retina, 15 inch, Early 2013)

## http://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/

## Symptoms

> An affected MacBook Pro may display one or more of the following
> symptoms:
>
> Distorted or scrambled video on the computer screen
>
> No video on the computer screen (or external display) even though the computer is on
>
> Computer restarts unexpectedly

Comment: You can read they T&C but bottom line it is up to Apples discretion to do what they think is the right ting to fix it.

Comment: You have to go to an Apple Store or AASP to tell if you qualify for that repair extension, and it doesn't cover a problem in physical displays (it's for a GPU problem, not a screen problem, and what they replace is the logic board). You may as well see if you qualify, but a display clamshell problem is not in the scope of the program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically Apple will replace (instead of repair) a computer that has required 3 repairs for the same issue.

It may require a call to Apple Care (800-273-2273) and ask to have the case escalated. If you have taken it to the store already, and the store has refused to replace, then Apple Care will probably back the store's decision. If however you call Apple Care first, and when they say to take it to the Apple Store for repair, you question the need for 3 repairs on the same computer for the same reason, ask to have it escalated, you will probably get offered a replacement.

If that gets you nowhere, You may also try a EECB (Executive Email Carpet Bomb) to various service level contacts. sjobs@apple used to get results, may try tcook@apple.com now? Or do google/consumerist search for EECB and Apple.
http://consumerist.com/2007/05/11/how-to-launch-an-executive-email-carpet-bomb/